# "No WiFi Adapter Found" - newly installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 on Dell XPS 13 (9343)

Tags: wireless, dell, broadcom

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 on my Dell XPS 13 (9343, 2015 model), replacing Windows. I am unable to connect to WiFi networks, the message "No WiFi Adapter Found". I have tried trouble shooting a few different ways:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling Broadcom drivers

```
sudo apt remove broadcom-sta-dkms bcmwl-kernel-source
```

```
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

- I also tried the below, but the /etc/init.d/networking command could not be found.

```
rfkill unblock all
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
sudo reboot
```

**System information:**

- Confirmed from the system BIOS:

  - Secure Boot in UEFI is enabled
  - Wireless Switch enabled (WLAN)
  - Wireless device enabled

**lscpci:**

```
Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

**sudo lshw -C network:**

```
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7200000-f7207fff memory:f7000000-f71fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: b
       bus info: usb@2:2
       logical name: enxeafbe91271bd
       serial: ea:fb:e9:12:71:bd
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ipheth driverversion=5.15.0-46-generic ip=172.20.10.2 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Many thanks to @chili555 & @ChanganAuto for finding the solution:

- Install correct driver with: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y bcmwl-kernel-source`
- Ensure UEFI is disabled
- Result of `sudo dmesg | grep wl`:

[   21.329436] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   21.329444] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   21.332750] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   21.337699] wl 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   21.489464] wlan0: Broadcom BCM43b1 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
[   22.216103] wl 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[  193.631249] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[  218.323695] Modules linked in: binfmt_misc rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep intel_rapl_msr mei_hdcp dell_laptop nls_iso8859_1 dell_smm_hwmon joydev x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_ctl_led kvm_intel snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_generic kvm rapl snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core intel_cstate btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm btrtl btbcm dell_wmi ledtrig_audio btintel snd_seq_midi dell_smbios snd_seq_midi_event dcdbas bluetooth input_leds uvcvideo hid_multitouch videobuf2_vmalloc wl(POE) sparse_keymap serio_raw wmi_bmof dell_wmi_descriptor videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev ecdh_generic ecc mc snd_seq processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy intel_pch_thermal processor_thermal_device snd_seq_device cfg80211 snd_timer mei_me processor_thermal_rfim processor_thermal_mbox snd mei processor_thermal_rapl soundcore intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal
[  218.323976] CPU: 3 PID: 658 Comm: wl_event_handle Tainted: P           OE     5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu
[  218.324129]  wl_bss_roaming_done.constprop.0+0xd6/0x120 [wl]
[  218.324296]  ? wl_bss_roaming_done.constprop.0+0xd6/0x120 [wl]
[  218.324462]  wl_notify_roaming_status+0x4a/0x70 [wl]
[  218.324632]  wl_event_handler+0x7b/0x1a0 [wl]
[  218.324792]  ? wl_bss_connect_done.constprop.0.isra.0+0x190/0x190 [wl]
[  228.051781] Modules linked in: binfmt_misc rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep intel_rapl_msr mei_hdcp dell_laptop nls_iso8859_1 dell_smm_hwmon joydev x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_ctl_led kvm_intel snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_generic kvm rapl snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core intel_cstate btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm btrtl btbcm dell_wmi ledtrig_audio btintel snd_seq_midi dell_smbios snd_seq_midi_event dcdbas bluetooth input_leds uvcvideo hid_multitouch videobuf2_vmalloc wl(POE) sparse_keymap serio_raw wmi_bmof dell_wmi_descriptor videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev ecdh_generic ecc mc snd_seq processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy intel_pch_thermal processor_thermal_device snd_seq_device cfg80211 snd_timer mei_me processor_thermal_rfim processor_thermal_mbox snd mei processor_thermal_rapl soundcore intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal
[  228.052034] CPU: 0 PID: 658 Comm: wl_event_handle Tainted: P        W  OE     5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu
[  228.052222]  wl_bss_roaming_done.constprop.0+0xd6/0x120 [wl]
[  228.052426]  ? wl_bss_roaming_done.constprop.0+0xd6/0x120 [wl]
[  228.052625]  wl_notify_roaming_status+0x4a/0x70 [wl]
[  228.052833]  wl_event_handler+0x7b/0x1a0 [wl]
[  228.053029]  ? wl_bss_connect_done.constprop.0.isra.0+0x190/0x190 [wl]
[  237.783615] Modules linked in: binfmt_misc rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep intel_rapl_msr mei_hdcp dell_laptop nls_iso8859_1 dell_smm_hwmon joydev x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_ctl_led kvm_intel snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_generic kvm rapl snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core intel_cstate btusb snd_hwdep snd_pcm btrtl btbcm dell_wmi ledtrig_audio btintel snd_seq_midi dell_smbios snd_seq_midi_event dcdbas bluetooth input_leds uvcvideo hid_multitouch videobuf2_vmalloc wl(POE) sparse_keymap serio_raw wmi_bmof dell_wmi_descriptor videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common videodev ecdh_generic ecc mc snd_seq processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy intel_pch_thermal processor_thermal_device snd_seq_device cfg80211 snd_timer mei_me processor_thermal_rfim processor_thermal_mbox snd mei processor_thermal_rapl soundcore intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal
[  237.783868] CPU: 3 PID: 658 Comm: wl_event_handle Tainted: P        W  OE     5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu
[  237.784056]  wl_bss_roaming_done.constprop.0+0xd6/0x120 [wl]
[  237.784245]  ? wl_bss_roaming_done.constprop.0+0xd6/0x120 [wl]
[  237.784430]  wl_notify_roaming_status+0x4a/0x70 [wl]
[  237.784623]  wl_event_handler+0x7b/0x1a0 [wl]
[  237.784802]  ? wl_bss_connect_done.constprop.0.isra.0+0x190/0x190 [wl]
[  247.986203] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready

Comment: Only Windows 11 requires Secure Boot enabled. If now you don't have Windows then you cam disable and, assuming the correct drivers have been installed, it'll will work.

Comment: The correct driver for your device can be installed with: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y bcmwl-kernel-source` Please do so, reboot and then edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep wl`

Comment: @chili555 - thank you! I made that installation, rebooted but it still wasn't working, so I then disabled Secure Boot and then it worked. I had tried disabling Secure Boot before and it didn't work, so seems like it was some combination of the two that worked. I pasted the result of the terminal command in my original question as requested. It looks like a few things may have failed/not installed properly (e.g. `module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel `) -- will this adversely affect other aspects?

Comment: @chili555 chili555's comment worked for the DELL G5 model notebook for now. It is disgusting that such problem persists since the Ubuntu version 14.04 LTS.